# Java XML - nested elements with same name

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

How can I reach to elements which have same name and recursive inclusion using Java XML? This has worked in python ElementTree, but for some reason I need to get this running in Java.

I have tried:

```
String filepath = ("file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*/*/foo");
```

Example

```
<foo>
  <foo>
     <foo>
     </foo>
  </foo>
</foo>
```

Comment: Which nodes to you want to select? Only the innermost ones? Is the depth fixed, or could it be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: depth is fixed */*/*/foo I have working model in python Element Tree, but my customer need it in Java (and using standard javax.xml.* modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that [`getElementsByTagName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) takes an XPath expression. It doesn't. As documented:

> Returns a NodeList of all the Elements in document order with a given tag name and are contained in the document.

If you need to use XPath, you should look at the [`javax.xml.xpath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-frame.html) package. Sample code:

```
Object set = xpath.evaluate("*/*/foo", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

NodeList list = (NodeList) set;
int count = list.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    // Handle the node
}
```